shdw-drive mac installation issue aug 2024
hi i was trying to find a place to upload the metadata image and everything and i see that lot of people use shdw drive
i am getting this following error
Error: 410 Gone:  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 410, "message":"The RPC call or parameters have been disabled"}, "id": "3494fb3c-1a31-48c6-b96b-86b893068e4c
kindly help
also are there any other storage places i could use for storage and getting the URI of a solana token program?
thanks in advance

you can refer to the FAQ docs, for further questions please reach out to the team & raise ticket
https://docs.shdwdrive.com/build/support-and-faq#im-getting-a-410-gone-error-when-trying-to-use-the-cli.-what-should-i-do
